# Are the following statements true or false?(calculus)

Tags: calculus, functions

Is there a continuous function :

(i) which has roots exactly at $1,2,3...$,

at the first time this function seemed to be right to me:

$ ||||x-1|-1|-1|... $ but this function has roots at -1,-2,-3 also, so I'm not sure that such a function exists.

(ii) which has roots exactly at $ \frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}$

I have the feeling that some kind of trigonometric functions can have these roots. A transformation of the function $\sin(x)/x$ seemed to be the good way,but this function is also even, so I mean also such a continuous function with $ \frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: You can basically build your own continuous function by choosing piecewise linear functions, where the linear parts "fit together" in the sense that the end of the one interval has the same value as the beginning of the next.

Comment: What about the following functions? $f(x):=\begin{cases}\sin(2\pi x) &\text{if $x>\frac{1}{4}$}\\ 1 &\text{if $x\leq \frac{1}{4}$}\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}f(\frac{1}{x}) &\text{if $x>\frac{1}{4}$}\\ 1 &\text{if $x\leq \frac{1}{4}$}\end{cases}$

Comment: A bit more difficult is to find holomorphic functions, but I think this is possible as well; anyway; for finitely many roots just take $(x - a_1)(x - a_2)(x - a_3)$!

Comment: @Wore Those do not look continuous

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: @kccu Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear that the first function is well-defined. If you try to define it as the limit of the functions $|x-1|, ||x-1|-1|,\dots$ then those don't converge. But as was noted in the comments, you can just define a piecewise linear function that has a sawtooth shape that you want. Since you don't want negative roots, just don't continue the sawtooth to the left of $1$ (choose some linear function that is never zero and makes the whole function continuous, though).

You can do a similar thing for any finite number of roots, in particular $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: The function $||x-1|-1|$ has also a root at $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, and OP also noted that as you continue with $||||x-1|-1|-1|-1|$ and so on you get roots at negative integers.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following function, that only have roots $1,2,3,\ldots$: $$f(x):=\begin{cases}\sin(2\pi x) &\text{if $x>\frac{1}{4}$}\\ 1 &\text{if $x\leq \frac{1}{4}$}\end{cases}.$$

In the second case, if $g(x)$ is a continuous function and $g(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for every $n=1,2,\ldots$, then necessarily you will have $g(0)=0$.

For a continuous function that only have roots $0,\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\ldots$ you can take:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin(2\pi/x)}{x} &\text{if $x>0$}\\ x^2 &\text{if $x\leq 0$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: It's not clear whether OP wants a function with roots at $1,1/2,1/3$ or $1,1/2,1/3,\dots$. In the second case, it's impossible to find such a continuous function because it must then also have a root at $0$.

Comment: Is there any "easy" way to show the roots of $\sin(2\pi x)$ ?

Comment: @kcuu I thought this was the case given that he wrote $\ldots$ in several places. I also explained that $0$ has to be also a root in the second case in my answer

Comment: @Zauberkerl The function $\sin(\theta)$ is equal to zero whenever $\theta=2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. Notice that I divided the function in two cases to avoid the negative roots, and the root $x=0$.

Comment: that's was really trivial, sorry because of the question, I appreciate your quick answer

Comment: @Zauberkerl No problem!

Comment: Where is continuous  $ \sin(2\pi x) $ if $x$ rational and, $0$ if it's irrational?

Comment: Both functions are continuous in all the reals!